# I'm trying to install gdebi.deb in my Ubuntu 12.04 and can't seem to do it

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install the gdebi.deb package on my computer.  I need to do it manually through the terminal, but I have tried the `sudo install -I package.deb` but says it doesn't work because it's not a directory or something.  Then I did `cd /home/user/downloads/package.deb` and when it changed directories I did `sudo install -I package.deb` but the same thing came up. I've already downloaded gdebi.deb in my downloads but need to install it through the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please cd to the folder containing the .deb file and use `sudo dpkg -i gdebi.deb`. See the man page on dpkg for more info. If you require any more help, I'll assist further.

Comment: okay thank you so much! I had to change the directory to /downloads and then use the sudo dpkg and it seemed to work but it said errors were encounterd so not sure what that means

Comment: This is the usual way to manually install packages; however, can you specify what warnings or errors were encountered? Often, they can be minor: in dpkg language, 'W: ...' means warnings and 'E: ...' means errors.

Comment: If you enter in the terminal, tail -n 30 /var/log/dpkg.log it should say 'status installed <package>' if it has been successful.

Comment: please do a dependency fix operation by typing `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 2):

"sudo install" isn't an appropriate command to achieve what you want.This, however, is:
`sudo dpkg -i package.deb`

Comment: Always use `dpkg` to install off-line package.